# How to use GROUP BY and get the last string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

Basically the question is how to get from this:

```
group    string
1        A
1        B
2        C
```

to this:

```
group    string
1        B
2        C
```

B needs to be the last row in the group

Comment: So you really don't want id in the result (remove from question if so)? Is the string ordered ascending? What MySQL version?

Comment: When you remove `id` you still have `string` column with different value..

Comment: sorry, i don`t really care about the id, just about the last string with group by.

Comment: string DESC - mysql 5.7

Comment: There is no such thing as "the last row in the group".  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets!

Answer (score 0):

```
select [group], max(Id) as maxID
into ##grouped
from myTable
group by [group]

select t.[group], t.string
from myTable t
inner join ##grouped g
on g.id = t.id
```

Comment: probably best to answer in MySQL form of SQL since that's what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
SELECT `group`, MAX(string)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY `group`
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8320c9/1
doesn't work when I have a text that's not ordered

Comment: so what do you want? Be specific.

Comment: @mark why do you need text to be ordered? You should read [Lexicographical Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

Comment: Sorry guys. I have a private messaging system and I want to select the conversation list with the last message of each conversation. I'm getting the first message right now and looks like a simple order by should resolve that case, but it's not.

Comment: There should be `date` when send message.. You can do order from that column.. Not with `text`.. It will get you the first text and the latest text..